# URL To Resource Folder

Tags: java, spring-boot, react-native

I have a React Native mobile app with an image slider feature included. I also have an API resource developed using Spring Boot.

I want to be able to load images into the slider from an API request. I've already created the API resource that returns a list of image objects but I want to include the URL link in the objects to where the images are located on the server. See example

```
[
  {
    name: 'Banner name 1',
    website: 'http://www.place-to-go.com',
    link_to_image: 'http://mydomain/folder/to/banner1.jpg'
  },
  {
    name: 'Banner name 2',
    website: 'http://www.place-to-go-next.com',
    link_to_image: 'http://mydomain/folder/to/banner2.jpg'
  },
  ...
]
```

How do I expose the images resource folder to the mobile app in a URL format as shown above?

Comment: The resource folder isn't exposed by default. How exectly do you want to make it available? How exactly do you currently have the resources?